# Java rest service 404ing

Tags: java, rest, maven, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I'm attempting to create and deploy a restful Web Service, however I cannot call any of my methods when it is deployed. 
I'm attempting to deploy it on AWS' Elastic Beanstalk, however when it is deployed I cannot access any of the resources beyond the welcome page.

Netbeans recognises the methods, and will show the method, (in this case a simple hello world method that returns a string to the user saying hello), and if I view the AWS access logs the server is receiving the requests and they don't look malformed.

It is a Maven Web Service, running on Tomcat 8, and I have produced the following through the use of multiple tutorials, however always run in to the same problem of being unable to call the method, as it just results in a 404.

Log Sample:

```
209.93.122.164 - - [01/Dec/2016:01:09:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 352 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36 OPR/41.0.2353.69"
209.93.122.164 - - [01/Dec/2016:01:09:38 +0000] "GET /test/h HTTP/1.1" 404 992 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36 OPR/41.0.2353.69"
```

Deployment Link:
http://sample-env-3.3ryvtqr8zj.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

Project Structure:
[http://i.imgur.com/vGWBBqE.png](https://i.imgur.com/vGWBBqE.png)

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Index.jsp (Most likely irrelevant, but including anyway):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>My First JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

test.java:

```
package com.mycompany.testdeployaws;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/h")
public class test {
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String helloWorld(){
    return "Hello world";

}
}
```

And finally, pom.xml as it is a Maven build:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>TestDeployAWS</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>TestDeployAWS</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: what is the name of your tomcat webapp.  If it is `tomcatApp` then a GET like `/tomcatApp/test/h` should work

Comment: @scarywombat I'm guessing you mean the name of the project, which is TestDeployAWS, however a get request to http://sample-env-3.3ryvtqr8zj.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/TestDeployAWS/test/h still returns a 404.

Comment: so does `http://sample-env-3.3ryvtqr8zj.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/TestDeployAWS` so maybe it is not deployed?

Comment: The base URI of http://sample-env-3.3ryvtqr8zj.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com shows the index.jsp page, so I'd assume it's deployed, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: looks like it is deployed as (or in) your ROOT project.  Just check your tomcat webapps directory

Comment: If you're referring to the Root folder of my tomcat install, there's nothing in there with the exception of Tomcat's default files.

Comment: OK, maybe url rewriting or something?  Try changing to have a `welcome-file>` in your web.xml to say index.html and chuck some content in index.html and then try accessing `http://sample-env-3.3ryvtqr8zj.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.co‌​m/TestDeployAWS`  If it works then maybe something else

Comment: Have tried that, still nothing. Either way, in all the tutorials I've looked at it should just be a case of http://beanstalk/method and it works. I genuinely have no idea what's going wrong as I've followed at least 5 different tutorials to the letter and nothing works.

Comment: maybe a AWS setting problem - have you tried locally?

Comment: I have tried it locally and it does not like anything other than the index.jsp page. There obviously is some reason it's not working, however it has no apparent reason not to and I'm completely lost.

Comment: check your catalina logs to make sure it loaded.  BTW are you class file correctly included in WEB-INF/classes ?